# TypeError: this.props.persistor.subscribe is not a function Redux Persist

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I'm incorporating redux-persist into my react app, and am getting the following error: 
TypeError: this.props.persistor.subscribe is not a function

I am following the same documentation described in the following link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

store.js

```
import {applyMiddleware,createStore,combineReducers} from "redux"
import {createLogger} from "redux-logger"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware"
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web and AsyncStorage for react-native

import reducer from "./Reducers"
const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(),thunk,createLogger())
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer)

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer,middleware)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
}.js:
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from "./store"
import persistor from "./store"

import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

ReactDOM.render(
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <Provider store={store}>
                <MuiThemeProvider>
                    <App />
                </MuiThemeProvider>
        </Provider>
    </PersistGate>,


    document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: At first glance, should you call middleware like this? Should be `applyMiddleware(promise, thunk, createLogger)`

Comment: Which redux-persist version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`import {store, persistor} from 'your-store-module'` is definitely the correct import syntax.

I suggest double checking your export statements and paths.

Answer (score 0):

Just export your store and persitor like this:

```
export default {store, persistor};
```

Then on you reducer import it like this (where the `store` and `persistor` are defined):

```
import Store from 'yourModuleName'
```

Lastly, call your `persistor` and `store` and put `PersistGate` inside the `Provider` like this:

```
<Provider store={Store.store}>
     <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={Store.persistor}>
         <MuiThemeProvider>
            <App />
         </MuiThemeProvider>
     </PersistGate>,
</Provider>
```